# Getting Segmentation Error in code

Tags: c++, vector, error-handling

Trying to create a function which will fill a vector of objects with initialized objects.
Please help.
ERROR: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

EDIT:

Ok so, problem seems to be occurring in the line when trying to access OBJ[0].age.

Also forgot the Point2d function comes from OpenCV libraries which I forgor to add, but they dont seem to contribute to the error in any way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct objtracker
{

int age;
vector<int> frID;
vector<Point2d> cent;
    objtracker()
    {
        age = 1;        
    }
    ~objtracker()
    {
    // Destroy ObjectTracker
    }
};

vector<objtracker> OBJ;

void create_new_tracker(vector<objtracker> OBJ,Point2d cent,int frameID,objtracker O){


    O.cent.push_back(cent);
    O.frID.push_back(frameID);


}
int main(){

    Mat Y;
    Y = imread("hor.jpeg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Point2d J;

    J.x = 100;
    J.y = 100;
    int frameID = 100;
        objtracker O;
        create_new_tracker(OBJ,J,frameID,O);
        create_new_tracker(OBJ,J,frameID,O);
        create_new_tracker(OBJ,J,frameID,O);
        create_new_tracker(OBJ,J,frameID,O);
        create_new_tracker(OBJ,J,frameID,O);

    cout<<OBJ[0].age<<"\n";

return 1;   }
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to replace your rant with a useful description of what your code is supposed to do and where it crashes ?

Comment: Embrace the change :-). Btw the old school way still works, but the libraries should make it easier for you.

Comment: Parameter `objtracker O` - that would be a *value* parameter. The caller's vector remains quite-empty. And `OBJ` is never populated with *anything* in this code, so I'm not surprised that subscript operator faults. Suggest [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and some re-ramp-up time would be in order?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, now have fixed it with more info. Ok so maybe call by reference?

Comment: @WhozCraig haha yeep dont know how I made that mistake. This is what is called a brain fart I guess.

Comment: I have rolled back to the previous edit. Solutions should be posted in the Answer box, not in the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   void create_new_tracker(vector<objtracker> OBJ,Point2d cent,int frameID,objtracker O){
O.cent.push_back(cent);
O.frID.push_back(frameID);
 }
```

You never add any `objtracker's` to `OBJ` inside this function.
And even if you did, it won't be reflected as it is passed by value
You might want something like

```
      void create_new_tracker(vector<objtracker> &OBJ,Point2d cent,int frameID,objtracker O)
      {
         O.cent.push_back(cent);
         O.frID.push_back(frameID);
         OBJ.push_back(O);
       }
```

Comment: So pass it by reference?